# How to place Sherlock ActionBar within Fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

How to place Sherlock ActionBar within Fragment?

I already have side-navigation, and all content placed in draggable Fragment. I'm want have ActionBar within fragment, and to drag it at the same time with Fragment.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't put an ActionBar in a SherlockFragment. The ActionBar lives outside of the Fragment, and inside your `SherlockFragmentActivity`.

Comment: If this properly answered your question think about accepting it as an answer so future users will benefit!

Answer (score 1):

The solution

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();
```